# UILabel loses text attributes the second time attributedText is set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, uisearchcontroller

I am implementing search using the UISearchController API introduced in iOS 8. I have a UITableViewController subclass that serves both as the search results controller and the search results updater. This controller is responsible for displaying the search results in a table view.

Every time the text in the searchBar changes, the search API calls the UISearchControllerUpdating method `-updateSearchResultsForSearchController:` on my table view controller. In this method, I update the search results based on the new search string, then call `[self.tableview reloadData]`.

I am also attempting to highlight occurrences of the search string in the list of results. I accomplish this by setting the attributedText on my table view cells to an attributed string that contains the highlights.

I'm seeing the following behavior:

1. After the first keystroke, highlights show correctly
2. After the second keystroke, all highlights disappear, EXCEPT
3. If a cell has a highlighted region at the beginning of a string, it will show all highlights, even in the rest of the string

After some trial and error, I have discovered that this doesn't seem to have anything to do with table views or cells and has everything to do with UILabel. It seems that the labels always loose the highlights the second time the attributedText property is set. Can I really only set it once?

### Some of my code

Table view data source:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString* plainCell = @"plainCell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:plainCell];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:plainCell];
    }

    JFDHelpEntry* entry = searchResults[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = [self highlightedString:entry.title withSearchString:currentSearchString];

    return cell;
}
```

The method that generates the text highlights:

```
- (NSAttributedString*)highlightedString:(NSString*)string withSearchString:(NSString*)searchString
{
    NSMutableAttributedString* result = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
    NSArray* matchedRanges = [self rangesOfString:searchString inString:string];

    for (NSValue* rangeInABox in matchedRanges) {
        [result addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:[rangeInABox rangeValue]];
    }

    return result;
}
```

The methods that finds the ranges to highlight:

```
- (NSArray*)rangesOfString:(NSString*)needle inString:(NSString*)haystack
{
    NSMutableArray* result = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, haystack.length);
    NSRange foundRange;

    while (foundRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        foundRange = [haystack rangeOfString:needle options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:searchRange];

        if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [result addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:foundRange]];

            searchRange.location = foundRange.location + foundRange.length;
        }

        searchRange.length = haystack.length - searchRange.location;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now convinced that my issue is being caused by a bug in UIKit, which I have reported. You can see it [on openradar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6658906893844480).

The workaround is to check if the beginning of the string has a highlight, and if not, add a clear-colored background color attribute from range 0-1.